# Is it OK to use ng-repeat again and again?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am building one application in AngularJS and I have very complex JSON file which have so many child arrays and objects. So my question is: for accessing the data from JSON is it OK to use ng-repeat again and again?

```
<div ng-repeat="parent in parents">
      <div ng-repeat="child in parent">
           <div ng-repeat="grandChild in child">
                {{grandChild.name}}
           </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

----- OR there is some looping method is available in AngularJS

----- OR we have to use old JavaScript `for` loop

Sample data

```
{"data":
    {
        "categories":
        {
            "articles":
            {
                "bdh":
                [
                    {"id":1, "name":"bdh article 1", "body":"this is bdh article 1 body."},
                    {"id":2, "name":"bdh article 2", "body":"this is bdh article 2 body."}
                ],
                "hadoop":
                [
                    {"id":3, "name":"hadoop article 1", "body":"this is hadoop article 1 body."},
                    {"id":4, "name":"hadoop article 2", "body":"this is hadoop article 2 body."}
                ]
            },
            "videos":
            {
                "bdh Videos":
                [
                    {"id":5, "name":"bdh videos 1", "body":"this is bdh videos 1 body."},
                    {"id":6, "name":"bdh videos 2", "body":"this is bdh videos 2 body."}
                ],
                "hadoop Videos":
                [
                    {"id":7, "name":"hadoop videos 1", "body":"this is hadoop videos 1 body."},
                    {"id":8, "name":"hadoop videos 2", "body":"this is hadoop videos 2 body."}
                ]
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends, I object is very big and you are nesting it again & again, may cause performance issue.

Comment: @Tushar heheh so it will not effect the performance of the application.... because for every single grandChild.name   ,   all ng-repeat will run again and again   :P

Comment: @PankajParkar so is there any other alternative

Comment: You should try to avoid the nesting, the performance depends on the size of data, if data is smaller(like this example), nesting is fine.

Comment: @Tushar   and if data is big than.... What is the solution :)

Comment: @Khiladi yes, by having angular custom filter over the data. Make data normalize and that will tend to use only single `ng-repeat` ( eg.  `<div ng-repeat="parent in parents | normalizeFilter"` then inner div will have all data )

Comment: You could consider limiting the first ngRepeat with the limitTo filter and use track by $index which will somewhat increase performance

Comment: If data is big, nesting should be avoided. Also, this indicates that the structure of data(_and hence DB_) need to be changed.

Comment: @PankajParkar the normalize filter will be applied on every iteration. How is this different in terms of performance than nested ng-repeats?

Comment: @Tushar   I added some data in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a deeply nested structure, and you want to access every item within it, then yes, nesting `ng-repeat`s is perfectly fine. It’s just like nesting `for` loops inside another to access all levels of an object.

Of course, if your object is very big, then you should consider not displaying everything, but that applies to all large objects regardless of whether they have the information nested or in a flat structure.

Comment: As commented by [@koox00](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35101631/is-it-ok-to-use-ng-repeat-again-and-again#comment57924320_35101631) `limitTo` filter is a good option for Big Data, you might want to add that in answer.

Answer (score 1):

It comes down to what do you plan to do with that data - if you **don't need any of the Angular features** like double-binding, etc, but **just to render the data**, you should probably go with plain JS (unless you only have a handful of objects), because those `$scope` watchers can be pretty heavy and expensive.

Otherwise, if you need Angular's features and/or have only a handful of objects, feel free to use `ng-repeat`s. In order to optimize it, for example, you can only show the data that fits on a screen and lazy load the rest when needed.